# What does YouTube mean when they say "key" in their documentation?

Tags: youtube-api

In the YouTube reference documentation found here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

It says:

"Every request must either specify an API key (with the key parameter)"

However, the language that is used in the Google Developer Console, they call credentials "Client ID" and "Client Secret"

Which one do they mean? Or are they talking about something completely different when they say "key?"

Comment: They mean the API Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key that the document is referring to is the API key. As stated in the link that you have provided:

> Every request must either **specify an API key (with the key parameter)** or **provide an OAuth 2.0 token**.

If you will be accessing user's private data or simply insert, update, and delete request OAuth 2.0 (clientID and client secret) must be use.

One example would be [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

If you just [list videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) using search keyword, request for a method that do not need to identify a particular user, you can use an application API key.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={API-key}&fields=items(snippet(title,description,tags))&part=snippet&id={video_id}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to figure out is, is my API key the Client ID or the Client Secret? I feel like the obviousness of this is clubbing me over the head, and I'm still somehow clueless to its existence.

Client ID = Identifies my application
Client secret = The password for my application
OAuth token = The token I receive from YouTube after the user authenticates my app
API key = One of the above? Or something else?

Comment: They are something else. When you create credentials in console.developer, you can either create an API Key or OAuth Client ID(client ID and client secret).

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's why I was so confused. I was using OAuth client ID. Thank you.